# Override syntax, specialized template method that returns a pointer to a fixed size array

Tags: c++, templates, overriding, eclipse-cdt, iar

Where should i put the override keyword?

Eclipse indexer throws an error in one example and my compiler with the second example.

Base class:

```
template<typename type, size_t N>
class Base<type[N]>
{
  virtual type const (& Get() const)[N];
};
```

Derived class:

Example 1) Eclipse error. Compiler OK

```
template<typename type, size_t N>
class Derived : Base<type[N]>
{
  virtual type const (& Get() const override)[N];
};
```

Example 2) Eclipse Ok. Compiler error

```
template<typename type, size_t N>
class Derived : Base<type[N]>
{
  virtual type const (& Get() const)[N] override;
};
```

Edit: The stack-overflow syntax highlighting also doesn't recognize override as a keyword.

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: `virtual type const (& Get() const)[N]` a virtual array of length N of references to functions called Get? Makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Eclipse CDT just says "Syntax error". And IAR Compiler says "expected a ;"

Comment: do you want to return a pointer or a reference?

Comment: eclipse complains, but what does the compiler say ? because `virtual type const (& Get() const override)[N];` is the correct syntax

Comment: you are missing `;` at the end of you class declarations

Comment: @RichardHodges it's a method that returns a reference/pointer to a `type[N]` variable. Example `double (*var)[3];`

Comment: @Tyker when using the syntax you mentioned the compiler doesn't complain. Note: I added the ; at the end of the classes, they were not missing in my real code

Comment: @vuko_zrno than its likely to be an ecplise bug. what you could do to improve readability and help eclipse is put the type of the return in a using declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion:

Make your life easier with judicious use of `using` (or `typedef`):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T> class Base;

template<typename type, size_t N>
class Base<type[N]>
{
public:
    using array_type = std::add_const_t<type>[N];
    using array_reference = array_type&;

  virtual array_reference Get() const;
};


template<class Array>
class Derived : public Base<Array>
{
    using base_class = Base<Array>;
public:
    using array_reference = typename base_class::array_reference;

    virtual array_reference Get() const override;
};

int main()
{
    auto x = Derived<int[10]>();

    auto br = static_cast<Base<int[10]>&>(x);

    auto&& y = br.Get();
}
```

But to answer your specific question:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<class T> class Base;

template<typename type, size_t N>
class Base<type[N]>
{
public:
    virtual type const (& Get() const) [N];
};

template<class T> class Derived;

template<typename type, size_t N>
class Derived<type[N]> : public Base<type[N]>
{
public:
    virtual type const (& Get() const override)  [N] ;
};

int main()
{
    auto x = Derived<int[10]>();

    auto br = static_cast<Base<int[10]>&>(x);

    auto&& y = br.Get();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/q16ns7

Comment: I agree that typedef or using is needed to clear the syntax here but why `std::add_const_t<type>[N]` instead of `const type[N]` ?

Comment: @Tyker good point. I was concerned that if `type` was `const int` then this would expand to `const const int`, but I am wrong. The compiler seems to be happy with it. however, in general I use std::add_const_t, std::add_lvalue_reference_t etc (if I remember) as I feel it increases clarity.